# How to communicate with backend in an empty ASP.NET web application template?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am used to working with PHP in the past as well as ASP.NET MVC. Now I am trying to learn to create an ASP.NET Framework web application, from scratch. I tried creating a project in accordance with the following steps:

Firstly I defined my project:
[image: Project template]

I clicked "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)" and then clicked the "OK" button:
[image: ASP.NET 4.7.2 Templates]

I clicked on "Empty" and made sure any references are ticked off and then I hit the "OK" button once more.

Now I have been provided with this simple as possible structure in my IDE:
[image: Simple file structure within solution explorer]

I know from my experience with PHP I used to be able to call backend code from within my HTML file (which is then a PHP file when I started developing in PHP). I also know from my experience with ASP.NET MVC I used to be able to reach backend code through the usage of controllers and Razor Views.

How would I achieve the same with the given template (empty ASP.NET Framework)? I know I could add like an HTML file (with controls such as buttons) and perhaps make calls using JavaScript and JSON. Would that be the way to go and if so, how would I start developing in that way?

How could I call a simple class in my HTML file? Or should I use something else than a simple HTML for doing this?

**My class:**

```
public class Sample
{
    public static string Foo()
    {
        return "This is a foo string through C#";
    }
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Call the C# class foo() method-->
</body>
</html>
```

**Folder structure:**

[image: New file folder structure]

Comment: The Web API/MVC controllers *are* the backend, they don't just communicate with it.

Comment: Okay, then I should maybe rephrase my question: How could I create my own backend structure using C# classes and call any methods within these classes to show any results within an HTML page?

Comment: @Barrosy have a look at mvc or razor pages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.0  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 1):

According to this requirement, we don't have to use MVC or Core or traditional Asp.Net to communicate backed class's method from simple html page.

It can be possible through Web service.

To create Web service, [ASP.NET development company](https://i-verve.com/asp-dot-net-development-company) is using class‘s method to create web service through simple html page, we have to follow below steps in visual studio:

1) Create simple class and one method inside class which we want to call from html page through Web service.

[image: this for testing]

2) Create Web service: Right click on Project > Add > Add New Item > Select WEB under Visual C# > Select Web Service (ASMX) > Add.

[image]

3) Call class's method from Webservice: #2 will create Simple Webservice file with one method. Create class's object in that method and call class's method through that object.

[image: this for tesying]

4) Now do AJAX call from simple (Index.html) html page which calling Webservice method.

[image]

5) This way, we will get result of Class's method through Webservice method from simple html page using JQuery AJAX call.

[image: this is for step]

Answer (score 0):

If your frontend is a HTML page and that is your structure, The only way you can bind your data is via Javascript/JQuery and AJAX.

Create a web service thru c# and call the web service on your HTML page using AJAX

Hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should learn the Razor Pages application model. A razor page is a .cshtml file with a code-behind file (.cshtml.cs) that acts like a controller.

Your Index.cshtml would look like:

```
@page "/"
@model IndexModel
<div>
    <!--Call the C# class foo() method-->
    @Foo()
</div>
```

Your Index.cshtml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace MyProject.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IndexModel()
        {
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public static string Foo()
        {
            return "This is a foo string through C#";
        }
    }
}
```

Also check out Blazor.

EDIT: There is more needed to get this example to work. Since you started with an empty project you would have to setup Program.cs, Startup.cs, make a _Layout.cshtml to handle the head/body for each page... It's better to start with a Razor Pages template instead.

EDIT 2: I realize now you are using ASP .NET, not ASP .NET Core. ASP .NET does not have Razor Pages, sorry. You should consider using Core. It's the future of .NET and will meet all of your needs and be more performant.